# Laravel SQL is not performing as expected. No syntax error

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

Can any Laravel developers help me understand why the following SQL statement is not working. I don't get any errors, it simply doesn't do what it should:

```
 DB::table('devices')
->leftJoin('hotel_device','hotel_device.device_id','devices.id')
->where("hotel_device.device_id","IS","NULL")
->delete();
```

This should remove all device ids where the leftJoin link returns as NULL (ie. where this device id is not being used in the "hotel_device" table).

If I run it as raw SQL directly in the database it works correctly. Note the "IS" condition rather than "=" condition, as I am refering to a NULL value. (using "=" didn't find any matching rows)

thanks.

Comment: I am positive eloquent uses `->whereNull('col')` instead of `->where('col', 'IS', 'NULL')`, could that be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `whereNull` method to compare to null rather than trying to filter it using the regular `where` method.

```php
DB::table('devices')
->leftJoin('hotel_device','hotel_device.device_id','devices.id')
->whereNull("hotel_device.device_id")
->delete();
```

Comment: Awesome, many thanks. I hadn't realised whereNull was a thing! Works perfectly.